# Unity is asking me to locate my Android SDK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

All I know is that I have my Android Studio in the applications folder, but it can't be selected.

I'm trying to build a unity project in Android. I'm also using Mac.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find out where Android Studio installed your SDK. You are using Mac but the steps below is for Windows. It should be the-same for Mac too.

1. Open Android SDK Manager
   [image]
2. Get the SDK Location 
   [image]
3. In Unity, go to **Edit**->**Preferences...**->**External tools** then put the Android SDK location into the SDK slot. Install JDK and put the JDK location in the JDK slot.

Comment: How about the NDK slot? Do I also need to indicate where it is?

Comment: @ChrisMikkelsen You don't need that for now. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just an add-on to the previous answer:

On the Mac the default location of the Android SDK is here:

/Users/[[Username]]/Library/Android/sdk/

(I would have added that in the comments but I still lack the credits for doing so.)